# How to get value from control created at runtime

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, runtime

I would like some help with the following issue:

I've got a mySQL/winforms application which is abbout clients and their requests. At some point I want to create a Tabcontrole. The tabs of this tabcontrole are created at runtime. The number of tabs depend on the number of request by the client. On the tabs a number of controls (textbox, button, e.a.) are created also at runtime.

Now I get to the point where I get stuck. How do I access the controls on the tab's to store their values in the database?

This is the code I use to create the controls:

```
 private void GetAllrequestsForSameClient(string client)
    {
        MySqlConnection MijnConnectie = new MySqlConnection(Constanten.DATABASECONNSTRING);
        string query = "select * from gedeeldeNotepadDB.requests WHERE requestsForeClient = '" + client + "';";
        MySqlCommand mysqlcommand = new MySqlCommand(query, MijnConnectie);
        MySqlDataReader myReader;

        try
        {
            MijnConnectie.Open();
            myReader = mysqlcommand.ExecuteReader();
            while (myReader.Read())
            {
               string onderwerp = myReader.GetString("onderwerpBijstandAanvraag");
               NieweTab(tabControl1, onderwerp);

            }
            MijnConnectie.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

In the reader I involke a method "NieweTab(tabControl1, onderwerp);"
This is the code:

```
public void NieweTab(TabControl tabControl1, string onderwerp)
    {
        TabPage tabPage1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TabPage();
        Label lblvan = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        Label lblPeriode = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        Label lblTot = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        MaskedTextBox txtPeriodeTot = new System.Windows.Forms.MaskedTextBox();
        MaskedTextBox txtPeriodeVan = new System.Windows.Forms.MaskedTextBox();
        Label lblDraagkracht = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        TextBox textBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        Button btnTabIsKlaar = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        btnTabIsKlaar.Click += new System.EventHandler(MyButtonHandler);



        tabControl1.Controls.Add(tabPage1);
        tabControl1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 111);
        tabControl1.Name = "tabControl1";
        tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 0;
        tabControl1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(533, 209);
        tabControl1.TabIndex = 38;
        //followed by a lot of layout code.....
```

I hope I've made clear what the question is?
Thanks in advance for solving my problem.

Comment: You have to keep the controls into a list (preferable create a usercontrol with all the controls in the Tab) and access them using a local list (list<usercontrol>). If you want the hard way... use a foreach this.Controls and search by name.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I don't understand what to do? Could you please give me some more hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to hold every control in a list so you can access them later.

First of all create a usercontrol with all the controls that needs to be populated from DB and accessed later.
Create Getters and setters for these control values.
You must be able to use the control somewhat like this

```
ucDBControl uc1 = new ucDBControl()
uc1.PeriodeTot = myReader.GetString("PeriodeTot");
uc1.Onderwerp = myReader.GetString("onderwerpBijstandAanvraag");
```

and

```
MySQLParameter onderwerpParam = new MySQLParameter("onderwerp", uc1.Onderwerp, NVarChar,20);
MySQLParameter PeriodeTotParam = new MySQLParameter("PeriodeTot", uc1.PeriodeTot, NVarChar,20);
```

Next step is to create a list to hold the usercontrols in the class for future reference

```
List< ucDBControl > myListControl = new  List< ucDBControl >
```

Later on, create the UserControl in the `while (myReader.Read())` and after adding that control in the list pass it to the function to place it in the newTab

```
    MijnConnectie.Open();
    myReader = mysqlcommand.ExecuteReader();
    while (myReader.Read())
    {
        var ucTemp = new ucDBControl();

        //create and initialize the usercontrol
        string onderwerp = myReader.GetString("onderwerpBijstandAanvraag");
        string PeriodeTot = myReader.GetString("PeriodeTot");
        ucTemp.Onderwerp = onderwerp;
        ucTemp.PeriodeTot = PeriodeTot ;

        //hold it in the list
       myListControl.Add(ucTemp);

        //and add it in the interface
        NieweTab(tabControl1, ucTemp);

    }
```

Then you must implement the NieweTab to add the control to the tab.

When you want to get the data from UI to post them to DB simple foreach every usercontrol and get the data from it

```
foreach(var uc in myListControl){
  //uc.Onderwerp must get the data from the text box
  //and use it in a MySQLParameter.
  MySQLParameter onderwerpParam = new MySQLParameter("onderwerp", uc1.Onderwerp, NVarChar,20);
MySQLParameter PeriodeTotParam = new MySQLParameter("PeriodeTot", uc1.PeriodeTot, NVarChar,20);
 //  Exec sql using the parameters out of the usercontrol
```

}

Comment: Ok thanks for the reply. This is what I need further down the road.. (-; first I still need to put the data IN the database from the tabcontrolTabs ?

Comment: What is your question exactly? How to get the data from the usercontrol or how you insert the data in the DB?

Comment: I want to get the data from the user control and insert them in the database. I think you were set on the wrong foot because the number (names) of tabs are retrieved from the database.  I've just been experimenting with a "foreach loop" to put the controls.text in a list<> but it seems only the controls from the last tab are added to the list.